# Flattening a multilevel linked list

Tags: algorithm, linked-list, queue, pseudocode

**Question**

1. Given a linked list where in addition to the next pointer, each node
   has a child pointer, which may or may not point to a separate list.
2. Given the head of the first list flatten the list so that all the
   nodes appear in a single-level linked list.

> ***Goal***.
>
> We need to flatten the list in such a way that all nodes at first level
>   should come first, then
>       nodes of second level, and so on.

[image]

The above list should be converted to

> 10->5->12->7->11->4->20->13->17->6->2->16->9->8->3->19->15

**My approach:**

```
1) Create an empty queue
2) while(Queue is not empty AND head.next!=null AND head.child!=null)
     2a) while(head!=null)
           if(head.child!=null)
               Enqueue(head.child)
           newList = head;
           head = head.next;
           newList = newList.next;
     2b)head = deQ();
```

Is this approach correct?

Comment: It's pseudocode but still isn't `Queue is not empty` equivalent to  `head.next!=null AND head.child!=null`. Other than that your approach seems correct to me.

Comment: There is a two-finger solution which works in place without an additional data structure. (OK, it needs the two fingers, but they're just node pointers.) I assume this is homework and you'd prefer to figure it out yourself, right?

Comment: @rici this isn't homework. Also could you or @aa333 point out the termination condition in line 2) of `while` ?

Comment: @Dubby: Ok, solution added. I'm sure I've provided this same algo for BFS elsewhere on SO. There is also a two-finger depth-first version where the child links are used to maintain the recursion stack; you might enjoy figuring it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple two-finger breadth-first (level-order) traverse which does an in-place flattening. (Efficiency freaks might want to rearrange the loops because some tests are done twice, but it hardly makes a difference.) The basic idea is that there is an implicit queue consisting of the nodes between `finger2` and `finger1`. `finger1` walks forward across the level and every time it reaches a node with no right sibling, the "queue" is advanced by walking `finger2` to the right until it finds a child, which is then appended at `finger1` so that `finger1` can keep moving to the right.

```
finger1 = finger2 = head;
while finger2 is not Null:
  while finger1.next is not Null: finger1 = finger1.next
  while finger2 is not Null and finger2.child is Null: finger2 = finger2.next
  if finger2 is not Null:
    finger1.next = finger2.child
    finger2.child = Null
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple stack based solution which traverses till next ends, then attaches the children from stack.

```
node *flatten(node *head) {
    stack<node *> s;
    node *curr = root;
    while (1) {
        if (curr->next) { // keep moving in current streak
            if (curr->child)
                s.push(curr);
            curr = curr->next;
        }
        else { // attach child branch and continue from there
            if (s.empty())
                return head;
            curr->next = s.top()->next;
            s.top()->next = NULL;
            s.pop();
            curr = curr->next;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your solution fails on the given testcase. Also, it will crash if head is NULL.